# React doesn't recognize user attributes in Amplify app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I built an Amplify app with Cognito user pools for authentication/authorization. I am now trying to retrieve user attributes using `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` . The example code they have (which works well) is the following:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
  bypassCache: false
})
  .then((user) => console.log(user))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Here, the `console.log(user)`  logs all of the current user data, as expected. I would like to now capture that data (or at least individual attributes of it) in a variable that I can use later on. However, if I try to define a variable using `user` it gives me an undefined error.

Here is an example of what I have tried and the error generated:

**Code:**

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
  bypassCache: false
})
  .then((user) => console.log(user))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  let userData = user;
```

**Error:**

`'user' is not defined  no-undef`

I have also tried `const` and `var` but no matter what, it does not recognize `user` . I don't understand how this is possible since it is successfully logged two lines above. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to store the values within a `const` by putting it inside of a try/catch block:

```
try {
  const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(); 
  const userGroup = user;
  console.log(user);
} catch (err) {}
```

In my case, I only wanted the user group, so I actually narrowed it down to that parameter:

```
const userGroup = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]
```